# Convert empty string to null using custom annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, annotations

I would like to annotate the String field. E.g:

```
@EmptyToNull
String name
```

I don't want to validate the field. I would like to convert blanks to null when sending an empty value for a String in DTO. Maybe there is a solution with Jackson Data Processor? E.g:

```
@JsonSetter(nulls = Nulls.AS_EMPTY) *changes null to empty*
```

I need an annotation with logic, but can't find an example anywhere. Someone help?

Comment: An easy way (not with annotations, though) would be to put the logic in your setter.

Answer (score 1):

### **Deserialization**

Extend [StringDeserializer](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/latest/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StringDeserializer.html)

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;

public class EmptyToNull extends StringDeserializer {
    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        String result = super.deserialize(parser, ctx);
        if (result != null && result.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Use `EmptyToNull` deserializer for specific field. It will look like custom annotation

```java
public class MyClass {
    public String title;
    @JsonDeserialize(using = EmptyToNull.class)
    public String name;
}
```

Also, you can register the deserializer globally for all strings for `ObjectMapper`

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(String.class, new EmptyToNull()));
```

**Alternative solution**

Implement logic in constructor

```java
public class MyClass {
    private String title;
    private String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyClass(@JsonProperty("title") String title,@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.title = title;
        this.name = name!= null && name.isEmpty() ? null : name;
    }
}
```

Or create custom setter for field

```java
public class MyClass {
    private String title;
    private String name;

    @JsonSetter
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name != null && name.isEmpty() ? null : name;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

### **Serialization**

Jackson provides out of box annotation [@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonInclude.Include.html#NON_EMPTY) to skip empty strings in case serialization.

```java
public class MyClass {
    public String title;
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
    public String name;
}
```